# PHP select image path and show if mainimage

Tags: php

I have images in a folder and I'm storing their path into database. Each have an 'is_mainimage' cell, which can be 0 and 1.
I'd like to select them and display the main images on bootstrap cards. If there is no main image for a card, it should display a static image. For some reason it doesn't display anything if there's no main image.
If there is main image, it works good.

```
<?php
// Main image
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE productid=? AND is_mainimage=?";
$stmt6 = $link->prepare($sql3);
$stmt6->bind_param("ii", $productid, $is_mainimage);
$productid = $row['id'];
$is_mainimage = 1;
$stmt6->execute();
$result3 = $stmt6->get_result();
$data3 = $result3->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);



$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result3);
echo $num_rows;
foreach ($data3 as $rec2) {
    
    if ($num_rows > 0) {
        $mainimage = $rec2['thumbnailimage'];
    } else {
        $mainimage = "images/no-image.png";
    }
echo "<img src='" . $mainimage . "' class='card-img-top' alt='Main Image'/>";
}
?>
```

database:

```
id | productid | thumbnailimage | is_mainimage

1  |  100      | uploads/image.jpg | 0 
2  |  100      | uploads/image2.jpg | 1 
3  |  100      | uploads/image3.jpg | 0 
4  |  101      | uploads/image4.jpg | 0 
5  |  101      | uploads/image5.jpg | 1 
6  |  101      | uploads/image6.jpg | 0
```

Comment: What do you mean by "use column in iteration"?

Answer (score 0):

The code below I wrote does this;

First, get all of the thumbnails of a product and check them. If there is an image set as "main image", assign it to $mainimage variable. Store other images in an array. You can use this array to show these images on your modals.

```
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE productid = ?";

$stmt6 = $link->prepare($sql3);
$stmt6->bind_param("ii", $productid, $is_mainimage);

$productid = $row['id'];
$is_mainimage = 1;

$stmt6->execute();

$result3 = $stmt6->get_result();
$data3 = $result3->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$thumbnails = [];
$i = 0;

foreach ($data3 as $rec2) {
    if($rec2['is_mainimage'] == 1) {
        $mainimage = "<img src='" . $rec2['thumbnailimage'] . "' class='card-img-top' alt='Main Image'/>";
    } else {
        $thumbnails[$i++] = $rec2['thumbnailimage']
    }
}
```

To show main image;

```
echo $mainimage;
```

To show other images;

```
foreach($thumbnails as $image) {
    echo "<img src='" . $image . "' class='card-img-top'/>";
}
```

Comment: It displays the "no-image" where isn't main image availabe, but if there's availabe, it displays an other one. Gonna edig my question with a part of my database so you can see what i mean.

Comment: Edited it, please take a look at it. And I think I need the foreach because I use the other data below.

Comment: If you have only 1 thumnail set as "is_mainimage = 1" per product, still you do not need foreach with the query "SELECT * FROM images WHERE productid = $productid AND is_mainimage = 1". If you want to get all of the thumbnails with 1 query then you should use foreach as you sad. But in that situation, you should use this query: "SELECT * FROM images WHERE productid = $productid". Let me know what you want to do exactly and I can edit my answer for you.

Comment: I have maximum 1 "is_mainimage = 1" per product. I'd like to display each of them on different bootstrap cards. But I'm also displaying where "is_mainimage = 0" on "modals" when a user click on the card.

Comment: I have edit my answer, check it out. If I helped you, I would appreciate that you accepting my answer.

Comment: It doesn't display any images.

Comment: Yes because you should print them. I have edit my answer again.

Comment: It only shows "no-image.png" if I add it to the else {} part